# How to perform Datatable Natural Sorting in Service Implementation?

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have implemented Datatable as a service,and i have a column for employees by Id E1, E2, E3,...,E100 and so on. But when i use normal order it sorts 1,10,11,....
I used the natural sort plugin, but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my getCustomParameters function. Any ideas on this?

```
public function getCustomParameters()
{
    $parameters = [    
        'dom' => 'lifrptip',
        'buttons' => ['csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'reset', 'reload'],
        'lengthMenu' => [ [50, 100, 200, -1], [50, 100, 200, "All"] ],
        'order' => [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        'columnDefs'=> [
           [ 'type'=> 'natural', 'targets'=> 0 ]
        ]
    ];

    return array_merge($this->getBuilderParameters(), $parameters);
}
```

Comment: which datatable version you are using for your application?

Comment: I am using 1.10.19